# Write python code that execute python scripts

Tags: python

I have a Python file (sql_script.py) with some methods to add/modify data into a SQL database, say

- import_data_into_specifications_table
- import_data_into_linkage_table
- truncate_linkage_table
- ....(do_other_stuff_on_db)
- connect_db

Sometimes I have to call only one of the methods, some others several of them

Until now what I did was modify the main method according to what I needed to do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = connect_db()
    import_data_into_specifications_table(conn= conn)
    import_data_into_linkage_table(conn=conn)
    conn.close()
```

But I find it a bad practice, as I always have to remember removing the main before committing the code

A possible option could be to write an external python file, say launch_sql_script.py), in which I write all possible combinations of methods I have to run, say:

```
def import_spec_and_linkage():
    conn = connect_db()
    import_data_into_specifications_table(conn= conn)
    import_data_into_linkage_table(conn=conn)
    conn.close()

...
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import_spec_and_linkage()
```

It can be useful to version this file, but still I will need to modify the main code according to what I need to do.

Do you think this is a good practise? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use program arguments mechanism: describe intended action during script execution.

Get a peek at [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=argv#sys.argv)

Here is the scratch:

```
def meow():
    print("Meow!")
def bark():
    print("Bark!")
def moo(): 
    print("Moo!")

actions = {
    "meow": meow,
    "bark": bark,
    "moo": moo,
}

from sys import argv
actions[argv[1]]()
```

If you're going to parse sophisticated program arguments, check out [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Separate them into individual scripts and run each from command line

```
# import_data_into_specifications_table.py
if name == '__main__':
    conn = connect_db() # import from a shared fiel
    import_data_into_specifications_table(conn= conn)


# in bash
$ import_data_into_specifications_table
```

Option 2: Write one file that parses command line arguments

```
# my_sql_script.py
if name == '__main__':
    conn = connect_db()

    if args.spec_table: # use argumentparser to get these
        import_data_into_specifications_table(conn=conn)
    if args.linkage_table:
        import_data_into_linkage_table(conn=conn)
    ...

# in bash
$ my_sql_script.py --spec_table --linkage_table
```

I would favour option 2 if the order of the operations doesn't matter or is always constant. If there are many permutations, I would go with option 1.